# Error in setting text in edittext

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

I've set up two edittext fields and a button. The idea is if I key in anything 
in one of the text fields, press the button the exact value must be set in the
other field. Here 's my code.

```
  rf1.setText("" + rf2);
```

But when I run the program (input say 24, press button) a strange message is displyed in the other text field saying

> "android.widget.EditText.....blah.

Any ideas anyone ??

Comment: You're not getting the contents of rf2 properly, posting some code to show how you set it up will help someone actually give a good answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that rf1 and rf2 are your `EditText` fields, you are not converting it to a string before setting the text.

Try this:

```
String strRf2 = rf2.getText().toString();
```

Then use `setText()`

```
rf1.setText("" + strRf2);
```